# Why |w|>=m in pumping lemma?

Tags: automata

If `L` is a regular language, then there exists a constant `n`
(which depends on `L`) such that for every string `w` in the language `L`, such that the length of `w` is greater
than or equal to `n`, we can divide `w` into three strings, `w = xyz`.

what my question is that, why we should pick `w` greater than or equal to `n`?

w = length of string.
n = Number of States.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the proof of the pumping lemma?  The rough outline goes like this:

1. If $L$ is a regular language, it is accepted by some finite machine $M$
2. $M$ has some number of states, say $n$
3. If $L$ contains a string $w$ of $n$ or more symbols, then $M$, in accepting $w$, must go through more than $n$ states, and since it has only $n$, it must go through some state more than once. Call this state $s$
4. Because of this, the part of $w$ that takes $M$ from state $s$ back to state $s$ (call this part $v$) can be repeated as many times as you want, and $M$ must still accept the resulting long string with many copies of $v$, because it must still end in the same accepting state as $w$, having gone around the loop several times instead of only once.
5. Therefore $M$ must also accept this long string that results from pumping up the $v$ part of $w$.

But this crucially depends on the fact that $w$ takes $M$ around a loop from state $s$ back to itself; that is the whole argument.  If $w$ is short, it might not go through any state twice, and there is no loop to pump.

That's why you need $|w|\ge n$.

Comment: I got it , thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, the pumping lemma states that "In regular languages, every word that's at least length $n$ can be split into $xyz$ where $y$ can be repeated indefinitely." (Hence the "pumping", I presume.)

The $|w| \geq n$ constraint simply takes care of the "at least length n" part. If you allowed $w$ to be any length, the pumping lemma wouldn't hold.

Consider the language $L=\{aaaab^i|i\geq 1\}$, which is regular. If you allowed $w$ to be any length, say $3$, that length would be insufficient for the pumping lemma to hold - there's no word of length $3$ we can break up there.

Comment: How pumping lemma wouldn't hold? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can do much more than rephrase what I already said. :( (It's been a while since I concerned myself with that topic.) I'm glad the other answer was able to help you, though.